# issues when Iterate Map with list as value using groovy

Tags: list, groovy, hashmap

```
def map  = new HashMap<String,List<String>>() 
def list = new ArrayList<String>()
def list1 = new ArrayList<String>()
list.add("hello1")
list​.add("world1")
list.add("sample1")
list.add("sample1")​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
list1.add("hello2")
list1.add("world2")
list1.add("sample2")
list1.add("sample2")
map.put("abc",list)
map.put("bcd",list1)
def data = new ArrayList<String>()
for(e in map){
println "key = ${e.key} value=${e.value}"
// data = "${e.value} as String[]"
data = "${e.value}"
println "size ${data.size()} " --(B)

check(data)
​}
def check(input)
{
println "${input.size()}" ---(A)
for(item in input){
print "$item  "​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​}
​}​
```

I have to pass string[] to another java function from this groovy script. so I am trying to read the array list and then convert it into String array. But the problem is when I assign `{e.value}` to variable `data` and try to get the size `data.size()` (both step (A) and (B) ). and the `size is 34`. It is counting each character not the word as whole from the list. I want to iterate over each word from the list. Kindly let me know how to resolve this problem.

sample output is

```
key = abc value=[hello1, world1, sample1, sample1]

size 34
```

Comment: why do you convert your list into a (G)String (`data = "${e.value}"`)?  if you need to pass `String[]` instead of a `List<String>` you can simply "cast" it: `["a","b","c"] as String[]`

Comment: `data = "${e.value}"` isn't needed. Just use `data = e.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the groovified vesion of creating the map and accessing it:

```
def map = [abc:['hello1', 'world1','sample1', 'sample1'], bcd:['hello2', 'world2','sample2', 'sample2']]
map.collect{ println "key: ${it.key}, list: ${it.value}, and size: ${it.value.size()}" }
```

**Output:**

```
key: abc, list: [hello1, world1, sample1, sample1], and size: 4
key: bcd, list: [hello2, world2, sample2, sample2], and size: 4
```

If you want to convert a list to an array you can just do it:

```
def list = ['hello1', 'world1','sample1', 'sample1']
assert list instanceof List
def array = list as String[]
assert array instanceof String[]
assert !(array instanceof List)
```